# How to add outline border to item for floating ionic labels

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, material-design

Searched high and low but haven't had any luck. I'm going for the outlined textfield material design look for ionic inputs -https://material.io/components/text-fields#outlined-text-field

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Text 1</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this css to your variable.css or global.css :

```
.box {
        border-color: #403E39;
        border-width: thin;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

and call that css in html :

```
<ion-item class="box">
  <ion-label position="floating" color="primary">Text 1</ion-label>
  <ion-input></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-item {
    --border-width: 2px;
    --border-color: #403E39;
    --border-radius: 8px;
}
```

> You can also use ionic internal CSS custom properties instead of adding a new class to the project.
> The above code will work in ionic 4 or 5.